# How to use WndProc?

Tags: .net, winapi, visual-c++, c++-cli, wndproc

How to use WndProc Funection for a picturebox in my form  ?
i try it like this code but it not work and not any message send to my
 public: virtual void WndProc( Message% m )

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
namespace MyProject {
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void) {
            InitializeComponent();
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        }
    protected:
        ~Form1() {
            if (components)
                delete components;
        }
    private:
        System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox1;
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

        void InitializeComponent(void) {
            this->pictureBox1 = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox();
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(
                this->pictureBox1))->BeginInit();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this->pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(41, 27);
            this->pictureBox1->Name = L"pictureBox1";
            this->pictureBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(206, 203);
            this->pictureBox1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->pictureBox1->TabStop = false;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(292, 265);
            this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(
                this->pictureBox1))->EndInit();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
        }
    };

    ref class pictureBox1 : PictureBox {
    public:
        virtual void WndProc( Message% m ) override {
            __super::WndProc(m);
        }
    };
}//close NameSpace
```

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to set the `BackColor` each time the window procedure gets executed. You can set it in the constructor and dispense with overriding `WndProc` in the first place.

Comment: @Cody: See his comment to my answer.  He's using DirectX.

Comment: You should name your class and your field.

Comment: yes insert BackColor code to see my void WndProc is called or not

Comment: Is this a dupe of all his other questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided by SLaks is correct, and I agree 100% with his comments that you need to *understand* what the code means, rather than copying and pasting a magical snippet off Stack Overflow.

But I see you're still screaming about how you should write the code to use your custom `PictureBox` class (the one on which you overrode the `WndProc` function), rather than the built-in one. That's really a simple matter of changing all of the references to `System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox` to `pictureBox1` (your custom class). Of course, you'll need to change the name of one or the other, but I recommend choosing better names than the default for everything.

For example, try the following:

```
namespace MyProject {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;


    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:

        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: pictureBox1^ myPictureBox;
    protected: 

    private:

        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;


        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->myPictureBox = (gcnew pictureBox1());
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->myPictureBox))->BeginInit();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // myPictureBox
            // 
            this->myPictureBox->Location = System::Drawing::Point(41, 27);
            this->myPictureBox->Name = L"myPictureBox";
            this->myPictureBox->Size = System::Drawing::Size(206, 203);
            this->myPictureBox->TabIndex = 0;
            this->myPictureBox->TabStop = false;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(292, 265);
            this->Controls->Add(this->myPictureBox);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->myPictureBox))->EndInit();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }

    };




ref class pictureBox1  : PictureBox  {
    //protected:
    public:      
        virtual void WndProc( Message% m ) override {
                        __super::WndProc(m);
        }
    };




}//close NameSpace
```

Comment: Thank You very much "Cody Gray" ! i test it and work very gooooooood !

Comment: But i no want to make a new picture box class. i want to use my picture box form and no make a new picture box

Comment: @user572312: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean. You've already created a new picture box class. It's the one at the very bottom called `pictureBox1` that inherits from the `System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox` base class. If you want to make another picture box class, you can inherit from that one the same way as it inherits from its base class.

Comment: i want to define "virtual void WndProc" to my picture box in my form[no want to make a new picture box class] then when i press a key on my picture box WndProc call

Comment: If you want to add a *second* picture box to your form, you'll need to create a new instance of that class and use the [`Form::Controls` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) to [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add.aspx) it to the [`ControlCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.aspx).

Comment: 1.i drop a picture box control from tool box in my form so now i want to use WndProc for that [no want to make a new picture box class]

Comment: @user572312: No, you can't do that. You have to subclass (which means making a new picture box class) in order to override the [`WndProc` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) because it's marked as *protected*. Protected means that it's only accessible from the class in which it is declared and any class derived from that class. You can't modify the `WndProc` method for the picture box from outside of the picture box class. The `Form` itself has a `WndProc` method you can override, but it's not clear if that's what you need.

Comment: so how to  declare WndProc for my picture box in form class?

Comment: @user572312: Again, it's not possible. You can only override `WndProc` for your **picture box** in a subclass of the `System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox` class. You cannot do it from the form, or any other class. Each control, including a `Form`, has its *own* `WndProc` method that you can override from within that class, but *only* that class. What is your aversion to creating your own picture box class? Inheritance and polymorphism assure that yours will behave and can be used just like the original, only with whatever functionality you've added bolted on top.

Comment: my first aversion is "when i use new class i can't see any control in my form designer !

Comment: if possible can u make a new clr appication an put "your" code in top and you seen first aversion

Comment: @user572312: I'm pretty sure that's incorrect. I don't do a whole lot of C++/CLI development because I don't really understand the point, but in C# and VB.NET applications, once you build the application any custom controls are automatically added to your toolbox. You may need to make sure that option is turned on (Tools -> Options -> Windows Forms Designer -> General -> and set AutoToolboxPopulate to "True", which should be the default). The control will appear on your form at design-time just like the control it inherits from. For a picture box, it will look just like a standard picture box.

Answer (score 2):

You created a new class, but you never used it.
You need to change your picturebox to be an instance of your new class.

<strike>However, **don't**.</strike>

`WndProc` should not be used in .Net development unless absolutely necessary; here, it is not necessary.
You should use .Net events.

Comment: OK.  You still need to understand what your problem is.

Comment: **Do you understand what I said in my answer?**

Comment: @user572313 If you wrap your comments in pairs of asterisks, you will be able to **SHOUT IN BOLD** too which may help you get an answer.......